# Compile directive from dynamically inserted tag

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-compile

I want to create a dashboard comprising of several smaller "apps". I have the following markup (simplified):

```
<div id="rowcontainer">
  <div ng-repeat="appRow in dashboard.appRows">
    <div class="row">
      <div ng-repeat="app in appRow.apps">
        {{app}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`dashboard.appRows` keeps my rows which consist of my "apps" (`appRow.apps`).
When I click a button I want to dynamically add a directive by replacing the `{{app}}` placeholder with a directive-tag and then compiling (`$compile`) this very tag I just inserted.
The kicker is, in the click handler, when I updated my model, the DOM is not updated (obviously) in the function and `$()` will fail to find the DOM node.

For clarification:

I want to make this:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in appRow.apps">
  {{app}}
</div>
```

become this:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in appRow.apps">
  <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

and finally `$compile` the above to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="app in appRow.apps">
  <my-directive>CONTENTS OF MY TEMPLATE</my-directive>
</div>
```

Attempting this all in the same function does not work, calling `$scope.$apply()` throws an error (`$digest` already running) and I don't know if there is a callback. And finding the DOM element does not work. Thank you for your help or alternative suggestions.

**Further explanation:**

The directive `<my-directive>` could be any directive (`<my-directive>`, `<your-directive>`, ...). In my template there is a a place-holder `{{app}}` which I will replace at runtime with any of those directives mentioned (assume you click a button and the directive is replacing `{{app}}`). And then I want my directive to be working.

Comment: actually this would work fine...you don't need to $apply...There must be an error somewhere else..

Comment: and you don't need to compile

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but what you want is a `<my-directive app="app">` that will change its contents dynamically according to what app is. More specifically, `<my-directive>` will display a directive dynamically, depending on the value of `app`. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: I added a further explanation. I just want to insert any arbitrary directive at runtime into my template and have it compiled.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way I can think of is using a container directive to hold the compiled directive.

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('Test', TestController)
  .directive('appLoader', appLoaderDirective)
  .directive('apple', appleDirective)
  .directive('banana', bananaDirective);
  
function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.apps = ['apple', 'banana']
}

function appLoaderDirective($compile) {
  return {
    scope: { app: '=' },
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      // you might have to do camel case to kebab case conversion here, depending on your input
      element.append($compile("<" + scope.app + "></" + scope.app + '>')(scope));
    }
  }
}

function appleDirective() {
  return {
    template: '<div>i am apple!</div>'
  }
}

function bananaDirective() {
  return {
    template: '<div>i am banana!</div>'
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-repeat='app in apps'>
    <app-loader app='app'></app-loader>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Apparently I was thinking to complicated.